# What is the architecture behind GoogleUpdate.exe on windows?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm searching for elegant auto-updater architectures,
Any tipy on how GoogleUpdate.exe does it? Chrome is allways up to date,
no questions asked, no asking for restarts.

Any tips?

I do not want to use the updater from google, but learn, how the do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has released the source code for their updating tool, also known as *Omaha*, which means you can find out how it works to update software in the background without you knowing. It is available [at this Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/).

Also, Chrome doesn't usually ask for a restart because it updates when you're not using it, so it doesn't have to bother you to restart. But if you have Chrome open all day (like me), you'll eventually get a little upgrade arrow under the wrench menu, asking you to restart.

Comment: I do not want to use googles updater, but learn how they do it?

Comment: hm, the upgrade arrow is a nice touch

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open source projects that have the same aim as Google's proprietary updater.  For example http://wpkg.org/
And Google Update itself is now open source and known by codename Omaha http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/04/google-update-goes-open-source.html